# function remove and update total doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shopping cart that the remove and update_total doesnt work.
In my remove button it removes the **remove** but not the whole table. and in my update whenever I remove some products the total does not update.

JS code

```
function remove(id)
{
    var i=findpos(id);

    totalprice-=purchased[i].price*purchased[i].cnt;
    purchased[i].cnt = 0;

    $('#table_'+id).remove();
    update_total();
}

function update_total()
{
    if(totalprice)
    {
        $('#total').html('total: $'+totalprice);
        $('a.button').css('display','block');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#total').html('');
        $('a.button').hide();
    }
}
```

My table.

```
<table width="260" id="table_'.$row['id'].'">\
<tr>\
<input type="text" name="id[]"   value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>
<td width="60%"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="roomname[]" value="'.$row['name'].'" ></td>
<td width="10%"><input type="text" name="price[]" readonly="readonly" value="'.$row['price'].'" ></td>
<td width="15%"><select name="qty[]" id="'.$row['id'].'_cnt"  onchange="change('.$row['id'].');" >
<option value="1">1</option>\
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<td width="15%"><a href="#" onclick="remove('.$row['id'].');return false;"   class="remove">remove</a></td>\
```

Comment: i suggest you update values in a session

Comment: <?PHP
    session_start();


$_SESSION['total'] = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $plus = 10;
    $_SESSION['total'] = ($_SESSION['total']  + $totalprice);
    } Is this correct?

Comment: just initialize the total if its not set yet, it won't update since its always declared above your code, then just add up the submitted value to the current session variable (`session_variable += post_value`) on submission

Comment: Whoa I dont know how to start. can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tip for anyone trying to use this code. If you are using Chrome version 24 or up and FF 27, you will need to rename the remove() function in script.js, as these new browsers have a built in DOM feature named remove. Without renaming the function you will not be able to delete items from the cart. I just renamed the function itself and the call to it in 'addtocart.php'.

These must be the changes.
   function rmv(id)
   {
    var i=findpos(id);

```
totalprice-=purchased[i].price*purchased[i].cnt;
purchased[i].cnt = 0;

$('#table_'+id).remove();
update_total();
}
```

To call into addtocart.php

```
table width="260" id="table_'.$row['id'].'">\
<tr>\
<input type="text" name="id[]"   value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>
<td width="60%"><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="roomname[]" value="'.$row['name'].'" ></td>
<td width="10%"><input type="text" name="price[]" readonly="readonly" value="'.$row['price'].'" ></td>
<td width="15%"><select name="qty[]" id="'.$row['id'].'_cnt"  onchange="change('.$row['id'].');" >
<option value="1">1</option>\
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<td width="15%"><a href="#" onclick="rmv('.$row['id'].');return false;"   class="remove">remove</a></td>\
```